# Android Studio Dependency Errors

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

[image]

```
finished
build.gradle
Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.13.2
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
Failed to resolve: com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Games/AndroidProjects/app/build.gradle">app</a>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some text explaining what you are trying to achieve, what is going wrong and what you have tried to fix it. Please then also don't post images as visual impaired users cant help and searches on this issue wont be as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
api "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0-alpha03"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0"
api "com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0"
```